# What is the simplest way to re-size a material design icon in html and css?

Tags: html, css, svg

For example I have this html and css:

```
  <svg 
    id = "menu_top"
    onClick = {this.clickHandler}  
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M4 8h4V4H4v4zm6 12h4v-4h-4v4zm-6 0h4v-4H4v4zm0-6h4v-4H4v4zm6 0h4v-4h-4v4zm6-10v4h4V4h-4zm-6 4h4V4h-4v4zm6 6h4v-4h-4v4zm0 6h4v-4h-4v4z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
```

Here the icon is clearly set to 24 px by 24 px as you can see these dimensions in both the width, height, and viewBox properties.

I would like to change the dimensions to 32px by 32px.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest ist to remove the width/height and just let viewBox take over, then use relative sizing based on a container or css rule targeting the svg's `id` but you can also just modify the width/height attribute values:

```css
#menu_top {
  width: 32px;
}

/* for the second option */
svg {
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-menu_top {
  display: block;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
  <!-- just modify the width/height attributes directly, leave the viewBox as is -->
  <svg 
    id = "menu_top"
    onClick = {this.clickHandler}  
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M4 8h4V4H4v4zm6 12h4v-4h-4v4zm-6 0h4v-4H4v4zm0-6h4v-4H4v4zm6 0h4v-4h-4v4zm6-10v4h4V4h-4zm-6 4h4V4h-4v4zm6 6h4v-4h-4v4zm0 6h4v-4h-4v4z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
  

  <!-- define the size via css directly on the svg element -->
  <svg 
    id = "menu_top"
    onClick = {this.clickHandler}  
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M4 8h4V4H4v4zm6 12h4v-4h-4v4zm-6 0h4v-4H4v4zm0-6h4v-4H4v4zm6 0h4v-4h-4v4zm6-10v4h4V4h-4zm-6 4h4V4h-4v4zm6 6h4v-4h-4v4zm0 6h4v-4h-4v4z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
  
  <!-- or wrap it in a container of desired size and remove id -->
  <i class="icon-menu_top">
    <svg
    onClick = {this.clickHandler}  
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M4 8h4V4H4v4zm6 12h4v-4h-4v4zm-6 0h4v-4H4v4zm0-6h4v-4H4v4zm6 0h4v-4h-4v4zm6-10v4h4V4h-4zm-6 4h4V4h-4v4zm6 6h4v-4h-4v4zm0 6h4v-4h-4v4z"/>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
  </i>
```

Comment: So view box is always ... `viewBox="0 0 24 24"`

Comment: Yap, think of it like the "original" canvas the svg was created on, but you can basically scale that to your liking trough external mechanisms like css!

Comment: But an SVG is supposed to be mathematical , i.e. not Raster at all.  There should be no "original size".   What happens if you just remove the viewBox all together?

Comment: the `viewBox` does not have pixel dimensions, see [here](https://www.lifewire.com/svg-viewbox-attribute-3469829) for more information (more when you Google "svg viewBox")

Basically: "The view box is part of the canvas you want the viewer to see"

Comment: to clarify (updated answer above): you can also just modify the width/height attributes with your desired size (e.g. hardcode it), but I personally find it more flexible to choose one of the other two approaches...